# I would like to find the story I read in the late 70's about a woman with wings

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

A woman is discovered hiding in a tree. She has wings and is the result of some form of radiation event. She is sent for examination by a doctor. Later after release or escape she is flying when a winged man appears. He is the doctor.

Answer (score 1):

The plot element of the winged man turning out to be the doctor who examined her suggests that this is [Jenny with Wings](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?57861) by [Kate Wilhelm](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/ea.cgi?66). Other plot elements that you may remember:

- Earlier in her life, she had suffered an injury while flying, and she was found by another doctor who imprisoned her and intended to exhibit her as a freak.
- Her first attempt at a romantic relationship ended badly when she revealed her wings to her boyfriend - he believed she was an angel.